# Getting the height of the software navigation buttons?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a Nexus 5 and when display.contentHeight is returning the whole screen height, including the `Back`, `Home` and `Open Apps` bar. How can I exclude that bar from the height?

Answer (score 0):

Found in [Corona forums](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/36015-displaytopstatusbarcontentheight-messed-up-on-some-android-devices/?hl=%2Bnexus%20%2Bsoft%20%2Bbuttons), you can try this code to know the height of your screen:

```
local SCREEN_LEFT = Display.screenOriginX
local SCREEN_RIGHT = Display.contentWidth - Display.screenOriginX
local SCREEN_WIDTH = SCREEN_RIGHT - SCREEN_LEFT
local SCREEN_CENTER_X = SCREEN_WIDTH/2 + SCREEN_LEFT

local SCREEN_TOP = Display.topStatusBarContentHeight + Display.screenOriginY
local SCREEN_BOTTOM = Display.contentHeight - Display.screenOriginY
local SCREEN_HEIGHT = SCREEN_BOTTOM - SCREEN_TOP
local SCREEN_CENTER_Y = SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 + SCREEN_TOP
```